# How to change all "x" to "y" but only before (or after) initial "z" on each line?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

On each line in a text file I need to change all `.` characters to `#` characters, but only before the first `=` sign. So, stop processing each line after the first `=` sign is encountered.

If easier, do the same thing but only AFTER the first `=` sign is encountered.

Example 1:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc=ljk.qrm
```

Would become

```
aaa#bbb#ccc=ljk.qrm
```

Example 2, if easier:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc=ljk.qrm
```

Would become

```
aaa.bbb.ccc=ljk#qrm
```

Comment: While possible any solution using `sed` won't be nice because I believe you will either need to use advanced regex or advanced `sed` features like `if`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F= '{gsub(/\./,"#",$1)}1' OFS="=" input.txt
aaa#bbb#ccc=ljk.qrm
aaa#bbb#ccc=ljk.qrm
aaa#bbb#ccc=ljk.qrm
```

Comment: Kamaraj,Thank you! That did it. Take the rest of the day off! :-)